# how to destroy data from table in ruby on rails with eqaul to and not eqaul to condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I want to delete data from `spree_stock_items` where `variant _id` equals `@varians.id` and `stock_location` is not equal to `stock_loc.id`.I tried below syntax but not working.What will be right syntax ?

```
Spree::StockItem.where(:variant_id => @variants.id, :stock_location_id !=> stock_loc.id).destroy_all
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
Spree::StockItem.where("variant_id = ? and stock_location_id != ?", @variants.id, stock_loc.id).destroy_all
```

or

```
Spree::StockItem.where(:variant_id =>  @variants.id).where.not(:stock_location_id => stock_loc.id).destroy_all
```

Comment: Query is executed correctly but data did not delete from table .How to parmanently delete these data.

Comment: you just want to delete do not think on it associated objects then use `delete_all` instead of `destroy_all`

Comment: Yaa but till now I have not authorized for this due to less point. But I already clicked.

Comment: acccepting answer does not require any vote you need to click right  tick